# How to split this kind of data in android

Tags: android, string

Here is the

```
  string  one =[{"ID":5,"Name":"Sai"}]
```

how i get only id and name from this string

```
  Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\]]+)").matcher(one);

                    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<String>();

                    int pos = -1;
                    while (matcher.find(pos+1)){
                        pos = matcher.start();
                        tags.add(matcher.group(1));
                    }

                    System.out.println("getting data"+tags);
```

i tried this but it didn't work

Comment: `it didn't work` - what does this mean?  How about `[{"ID":5,"Name":"Sai"}].split(",")[1].split(":")[0];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>(one);
                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            for(int i = 0; i< array.length(); i++){
                JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                 ls.add(obj.getString("Name"));

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's JSON format and it can very easily be read in Android. Here is the sample code:

```
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(one);



            int length = array.length();

            for(int i=0;i< length; i++)
            {
                JSONObject temp = array.getJSONObject(i);

                System.out.println(temp.getString("ID"));

                System.out.println(temp.getString("Name")); 

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is a json formate Date 
use JsonObject class to parse this  data
tutorial [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidJSON/article.html)

```
    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("[{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Sai\"}]");
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        System.out.println(object.getString("ID"));
        System.out.println(object.getString("Name"));
    }
```

Comment: i know that but is it possible to split that without using json

Comment: @Kirti Yes, it is possible without JSON, but ***why?*** If you want to parse it, you have to define which format the input data will be, and what will be the output. Will you need nested structures? You can parse a JSON object into _(key, value)_ pairs, but if you need the general case with nested JSON objects and arrays, it's easier to use what other people wrote and debugged.

Answer (score 1):

This format of data is called JSON.

Have a look at Go to http://json.org/, scroll to (almost) the end, click on one of the many Java libraries listed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your string initialization is wrong.

**Wrong:**

```
string  one =[{"ID":5,"Name":"Sai"}]
```

**Correct:**

```
String  one ="[{\"ID\":5,\"Name\":\"Sai\"}]";
```

Second, its a JSON formatted data so you can parse it using [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html) and [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) classes, instead of creating any pattern.

Now, in your case its JSONObject inside JSONArray so initially create an object of JSONArray using your string.

For example:

```
  JSONArray arrayJSON = new JSONArray(one);   // 'one' is your JSON String
    for(int i=0; i<arrayJSON.length(); i++) {
         JSONObject objJson = arrayJSON.getJSONObject(i);
         String ID = objJson.getString("ID");
         .....
         .....
          // same way you can fetch/parse any string/value from JSONObject/JSONArray

    }
```